# Symfony 4 functional test not loading (child) entity properly

Tags: php, symfony, automated-tests

I want to functional test a controller that loads an entity given by the id in the url. That entity is loading a child entity. When I directly open the tested URL and dump the child entity everything is fine.
When I call the same url via functional test and read the content, the child entity is null. I already fetch the child entity "EAGER" but the result is the same as without it.

Controller called /parent/{id}

```
public function displayParent($id, ParentRepository $parentRepository)
{
 $parent = $parentRepository->findOneByCode($id);
 // Not 'null' when url is directly opened
 // 'null' when called in the functional test
 dump($parent->getChild());
 ...
```

Functional test:

```
public function testParent()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/parent/12');

    // Displays content of /parent/{id} but is always 'null'
    dump($client->getResponse()->getContent());
    ...
}
```

How is that possible and how can I solve this?

Comment: Do both development and testing environments connect to the same database?

Comment: @zerkms You are right ... it was too obvious and late for me to see that error x_x Thank you!